# How to loop through elements and their sub elements in order add or remove classes — Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a list of events – I want to only show the ones that are in the past. To do this I was thinking to loop though these elements, find the containing div with the date, and then compare this to todays current date.

A basic structure of these events is as follows:

```
<div class="past-event">

  <span class="event-title">Event 1</span>
  <span class="event-date">05.05.19</span>

</div>

<div class="past-event">

  <span class="event-title">Event 2</span>
  <span class="event-date">20.04.19</span>

</div>
```

I've used Moment.js to parse the dates. I've used jQuery for this so far (I usually try not to) but this is hosted on a Wordpress site anyway so jQuery is already available. I'm happy to hear any solution and not just a jQuery related one.

Here is a JSFiddle of a simplified version of my code. The way its laid out, the first two elements should be hidden and the second two should be blue (I have added a "blue" class to make it clearer when the code is not working)

https://jsfiddle.net/ngpvkscf/

Comment: Now is string, event_date is object - just console log this and you can see the solution on your own.

Comment: Your formatting the dates into strings.  That's for human consumption.  Compare the dates in JS notation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: @cale_b or since using moment already it has methods like `isBefore()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here:

- You're trying to create `event_date` as a moment object, yet you're passing the value of itself instead of `event_date_raw`
- The resulting dates will be a moment object and a string. For the comparison to work you need to equalise the types. I'd suggest using plain Date objects, so you need to call `.toDate()` in moment and use `new Date()` to get the current date time.
- You need to use `find()` to get the `.event-date` element within the current `.past-event`. Your current logic is only working with the first one.

With those issues fixed, it works:

```js
$('.past-event').each(function(i, obj) {
  var event_date_raw = $(this).find('.event-date').text();
  var event_date = moment(event_date_raw, "DD.MM.YY").toDate();
  var now = new Date();

  if (now < event_date) {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("blue");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: ; /* fix this too */
  margin: 0;
  color: #EEE;
}

.past-event {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<div class="past-event">
  <span class="event-title">Event 1</span>
  <span class="event-date">05.05.19</span>
</div>
<div class="past-event">
  <span class="event-title">Event 2</span>
  <span class="event-date">20.04.19</span>
</div>
<div class="past-event">
  <span class="event-title">Event 3</span>
  <span class="event-date">01.02.19</span>
</div>
<div class="past-event">
  <span class="event-title">Event 4</span>
  <span class="event-date">05.05.18</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/4dehv2pj/

```
jQuery('.past-event').each(function(i, obj) {
  var event_date_raw = jQuery(this).children('.event-date').text();
  var event_date     = moment(event_date_raw, "DD/MM/YY");
  var now              = moment().format("DD/MM/YY");
console.log(event_date_raw);
  if (now < event_date) {
    jQuery(this).addClass("hidden");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).addClass("blue");
  }
});
```

Comparing dates with moment.js is a little bit different than just a greater than/less than operator.

I'm using `moment(event_date).isAfter(now)`

This will get you the correct comparison.

Also by using `jQuery('.event-date').text();` you're getting ALL of the elements that match `.event-date`, so instead I do something like `jQuery(this).children('.event-date').text();`, which takes the current element and checks the children of the current element for that query selector.

Comment: Copy the relevant bits of code to your answer, so that when that fiddle disappears, this answer still has value to future visitors.

Comment: @cale_b thanks. Edited the answer to include the JS code in its entirety, with the explanation beneath.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you may need

```
    $('.event-date').each((index, item) => {
    var date = moment($(item).text(), 'DD.MM.YY').toDate();

    if (date > new Date()) {
        console.log(date)
        $(item).closest('.past-event').css('display', 'none');
    }

});
```